# convertir formato 1986-06-15T06:00:00.0000000Z a Date

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime

Desde un servicio recibo una fecha
1986-06-15T06:00:00.0000000Z

Y en la pagina la muestro con este campo :

```
<div name="datefecnac" id="datefecnac" k-date-input 
date="personaAlta.fecNacimiento" format="'mm/yyyy'"
placeholder="" ng-changed="checkDate();"  required></div>
```

Quiero convertir la fecha recibida a un formato compatible con date

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla de hacer parsing de esa fecha es de la siguiente utilizando Regex, elminas así los caracteres indeseados y los mandas al constructor de `Date`

Acá un ejemplo:

```js
let testDate = "1986-06-15T06:00:00.0000000Z";

function parseDate(date) {
  let dateArr = testDate.match(/\d+/g);
  
  return new Date(...dateArr);
}

console.log(parseDate(testDate));
```